# Como descargar todos los modulos en background luego de la descarga inicial en Angular 14?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

Hacer lazy loading por modulo es relativamente sencillo en Angular.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: () => import('./customers/customers.module').then(m => m.CustomersModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: () => import('./orders/orders.module').then(m => m.OrdersModule)
  }
];
```

Pero eso me obliga a descargar el modulo en el momento de navegarlo por primera vez. El usuario debe esperar la descarga inicial de cada nuevo modulo descargado.

Es posible descargar todos los modulos restantes luego de la descarga inicial, para no tener que esperar la descarga inicial de los de los siguientes modulos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes conseguirlo puedes usar la estrategia de carga `PreloadAllModules` del `RouterModule`. Usando esta estrategia se irán cargando en segundo plano **todos** los módulos.

Para ello simplemente tienes que añadir lo siguiente en el modulo donde importes el router:

```
import { RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';

...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules // <------
    })],
  
})
...
```

un saludo